# Prevent touch event from reaching to parent widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

In following example when `FlatButton` is clicked touch event is also propageted to `InkWell`, which displays ripple. Is there a way to disable this kind of behavior? So if touch is consumed by child widget it doesn't reach widget's parent?

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Dummy text"),
          FlatButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Button"))
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The event doesn't reach the parent widget. The flat button has that ripple effect by default. You can disable it setting the splashColor of the FlatButton to transparent. The same thing can be done to the InkWell.

Like this

```
InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Dummy text"),
          FlatButton(
           splashColor: Colors.transparent,
           onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Button"))
        ],
      ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit too late but if anyone is looking for the right answer. Here it is.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("Dummy text"),
      FlatButton(onPressed: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus();
      }, child: Text("Button")),
    ],
  ),
);
```

FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus() will make the button request the focus so the InkWell doesn't show ripples.